# LINQ many-to-many in WPF databinding path

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, data-binding

in my c# WPF app i add columns to a DataGrid at runtime, and populate from my SQL db via LINQ.  this is working fine until i try to add data from my many-to-many table

here's a simplified version of the 3 relevant tables my db:

```
documents: document_id, title
documents_keywords: document_id, keyword_id, value
keywords: keyword_id, name
```

what i want in my DataGrid is a column for document.title, plus a column for each record in document.documents_keywords based on user selection.  here's my code:

```
        DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Header = "Title",
            Binding = new Binding("title")
        });
        foreach (string keywordName in keywordsListBox.SelectedItems)
        {
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
            {
                Header = keywordName,
                Binding = new Binding("documents_keywords.FirstOrDefault(kw => kw.keyword.name.Equals(\""+keywordName+"\")).value")
            });
        }

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = from d in db.documents select d;
```

i'm getting the keyword headers, but the cells are all blank.  the binding fails at FirstOrDefault:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'FirstOrDefault(d_k => d_k.keyword.name.Equals("Order#"))' property not found on 'object' ''EntityCollection`1' (HashCode=7935090)'. BindingExpression:Path=documents_keywords.FirstOrDefault(d_k => d_k.keyword.name.Equals("Order#")).value; DataItem='document' (HashCode=5781744); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

what is the best way to accomplish this?  forgive me as this is my first jaunt into WPF and LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to rewrite your code, but it isn't an easy task and I'm not sure if it works.
I have set the binding of each column to a sequential index of an array `Keywords["+i+"]"` instead of `documents_keywords.FirstOrDefault(` and have changed a structure of the ItemSource.

I have no opportunity to check this code myself, so if you have any problems - write them in the comment section.

```
    DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
    {
        Header = "Title",
        Binding = new Binding("title")
    });
    //all possible keywords
    var items = db.keywords.Select(k => new {Id = k.keyword_id, Name = k.name}).ToArray();
    //selected keywords ordered by id
    var selected = (from item in items
                   where keywordsListBox.SelectedItems.Contains(item.Name)
                   orderby item.Id
                   select item)
                   .ToArray();
    //create columns and bind them
    for(int i = 0; i < selected.Length; i++)
    {
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Header = selected[i].Name,
            Binding = new Binding("Keywords["+i+"]")
        });
    }

    var documents = (from d in db.documents
                     select new{ 
                        d.title, 
                        //All related keywords
                        Keywords = d.documents_keywords.Select(dk => 
                                       new { Id = dk.keywoard_id, Value = dk.value})
                                      .ToList()}) 
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(doc => new {
                        title = doc.title,
                        //Only selected keywords with default null values
                        Keywords = (from si in selected
                                   join k in doc.Keywords on si.Id equals k.Id into j
                                   from ji in j.DefaultIfEmpty(new { Id = si.Id, Value = null})
                                   orderby ji.Id
                                   select ji.Value)
                                   .ToArray()
                        });
   dataGrid.ItemsSource = documents.ToList();
```

Comment: sorry for the late response - this project is far down the priorities list and i'm just getting back to it. your solution errors on the last line, but given the complexity i think i'll try a different approach.  thank you!